# How to secure Password and Salt on a deployed application

Tags: authentication, hash, salt

I have a question regarding one step of protection more than salt/hash.  I work on an application that is distributed to many clients and then deployed on their networks.  If I set a password on one instance of the application and then look up the generated salt and hash in the database, what mechanism can stop me from copying a known password's salt and hash into another instance of my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a per-instance salt as well.  This would be stored in the config for the application, and would result in different hashes for each instance, even for the same salt/password combination.

Now the question arises of *why* you'd want to do that.  If someone has gained read access to one database and write access to another, it seems they've already got quite a bit of access.  Why would they copy a salt & password over rather than (say) just inserting a new account?

Comment: One additional comment - A per-instance salt is also often called a pepper, so for anyone searching for more info, you might want to look for results discussing salt-and-peppering.

Comment: The question came up because it seems insecure that I can copy a known set of values (salt and hash) to reset a password. However, you are correct, if somebody already has database write access, they could do much worse than change an account's password to a known value.

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer since pepper looks to be a viable solution to the specific issue mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a client side application, which can directly connect to your database and see all usernames and passwords, then nothing will stop you.

This just means you have implemented poor access controls which also means you have a flawed security model.

Comment: The original question asked how to prevent an application from interpreting a salt/hash pair as being a valid password in a different instance of the application.  The question doesn't mention anything about a client application having free reign over the associated database.

Comment: The question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can prevent this from happening.

**Database level:**

**Constraint**
You could make a constraint on the table making salt and password unique and if you try insert a duplicate it will throw an exception.

**Stored procedure or your queries**
Do an check if exists such as `IF EXISTS( SELECT ...` if exists return an error.

You'll need to throw an unique identify in within your application if you want a password per instance and not a user. If the instances are all the same, why don't you use a username and password? If the instances are different then just checksum the instance of the application and throw it against password and salt check.

For the sake of your security I hope your using service to access the database and not directly from the clients otherwise you have more serious issue in your design.